# Dysfunctional prev button in slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have a problem in my code for a slideshow, and to me it feels like a very stupid one: I cannot make the 'prev' button work. Nothing happens if I click. The 'next' button does what it's supposed to do. I assume it has something to do with my javascript, of which I have very, very limited knowledge (means: no clue).

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);}

    function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);}

    function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";   }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", ""); }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";}
```

```css
.mySlides {display: none}
    img {vertical-align: middle;
    }


    .slideshow-container {
    width: 100%;
    hight: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto; 
    }

    .active, .dot:hover {
    background-color: #717171;
    }

    .prev {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left:5px;
    margin-lift: 5px;
    }

    .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right:5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mySlides fade">
     <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
     <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="imagelandscape"><img src="http://image.JPG" style= " display: block; max-height:auto; width:100%; "></div>
  </div>
```

the whole code is based on a simple w3schools slideshow. I'm very new to this, so I appreciate everybody's help and patience a lot.

Comment: can you please provide myslides and dot elements?

Comment: Can you please update your code with snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: well, the error that I am getting is simply that I cannot click the 'prev' button. Nothing happens. I updated the initial post as well, thanks!

Comment: your `js` checks out buddy, check whether click is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function init(){
    ul = document.getElementById('image_slider');
    liItems = ul.children;
    imageNumber = liItems.length;
    imageWidth = liItems[0].children[0].clientWidth;
    // set ul's width as the total width of all images in image slider.
    ul.style.width = parseInt(imageWidth * imageNumber) + 'px';
    prev = document.getElementById("prev");
    next = document.getElementById("next");
    /*.onclike = onClickPrev() will be fired when onload; is this because closure?? */
    prev.onclick = function(){ onClickPrev();};
    next.onclick = function(){ onClickNext();};
}
```

```css
.nvgt{
    position:absolute;
    top: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.nvgt:hover{
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#prev{
    background: #000 url('./image/prev.png') no-repeat center;
    left: 0px;
}
#next{
    background: #000 url('./image/next.png') no-repeat center;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Image-Slider-LnR.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Image-Slider-LnR.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="slider_wrapper">
            <ul id="image_slider">
                <li><img src="./image/1.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="./image/4.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="./image/5.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="./image/4.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="./image/1.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="./image/5.jpg"></li>
            </ul>                   
            <span class="nvgt" id="prev"></span>
            <span class="nvgt" id="next"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is this? this is not the solution